# Apache Airflow 2.0 Celery Executor Installation

Tags: rabbitmq, celery, airflow

I understand that for Airflow CeleryExecutor, celery and rabbitmq (or redis) are required.
Are the requirements fulfilled by simply running `pip install apache-airflow[celery,rabbitmq]` or do we need to run `sudo yum install rabbitmq-server` and `pip install celery`?

My question is for Airflow 2.0+

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If you install `apache-airflow[celery]` on a fresh virtual environment you will see that it already installs `celery` for you. Thus, `pip install celery` is redundant.
2. You do need rabbitMQ server (the actual process). Alternatively, you can use rabbitMQ in docker.
3. Not sure about `apache-airflow[rabbitmq]`, because I know that Celery use `amqp` protocol to communicate with rabbitMQ. `amqp==5.0.6` package is being installed with `celery`'s installation (which happened by `pip install apache-airflow[celery]`).